# Running test fails in django after GinIndex creation, ProgrammingError: relation "table_name_GeoLocation_id" already exists

Tags: postgresql, django-models

I have migrated Lat Lng float to PointField and Added GinIndex on models.

While running the test on Django, the test fails with the below error, Migration went fine.

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "table_name_GeoLocation_id" already exists

If I comment out below line on models, it gets passed. test_db seems to be trying to create an index twice.

Can I get some help on that?

**indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["GeoLocation"])]**

Comment: Hello can you edit your post to show some code so people can help you

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for this, Creating geometry field in geodjango automatically created index for us. Unless we specifically pass spatial_index=False to the PointField(), the index is already available.

Removing an explicit index **indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["GeoLocation"])]** from the above ques has actually solved the problem. Thanks!